Send data to API in Flutter every 30 seconds with App in Background
I have a Flutter application that needs to send location updates every 30 seconds to my API. I've tried using the Workmanager, flutter_background, and flutter_background_geolocation packages, but I haven't been able to get it to work correctly. When the app goes into the background, this sending should continue. I'm using Dart Isolates, and it only works when the app is in the foreground.
I use it with Cubit to send data to server. My cubit have a listener for the class BackgroundData.
   backgroundData.addListener((message) {
      sendData();
    });

This is the class that handles the background service.
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:isolate';
import 'dart:developer';
import 'package:core/core.dart';
import 'package:maps/map_mixin.dart';

Duration duration = const Duration(seconds: 30);

class BackgroundData with ScaleMapConfigurationsMixin {
  String? idScale;
  Isolate? _isolate;
  ReceivePort? _receivePort;
  final StreamController<String> _streamController = StreamController<String>.broadcast();
  StreamSubscription<String>? _subscription;

  void addListener(Function(String) listener) {
    _subscription?.cancel();
    _subscription = _streamController.stream.listen(listener);
  }

  void notifyCubitToSendData() {
    _receivePort?.sendPort.send('sendData');
  }

  static void _isolateEntry(List<dynamic> args) {
    Timer? timer;
    final taskId = args[1];
    final sendPort = args[0];

    final port = ReceivePort();
    sendPort.send(port.sendPort);

    Timer.periodic(duration, (timer) {
      sendPort.send('sendData');

      DateTime now = DateTime.now();
      log("BackgroundData - Send to server ${now.hour}:${now.minute}");
    });

    port.listen((message) {
      if (message == 'stop') {
        timer!.cancel();
        port.close();
      }
    });
  }

  void startTask(String taskId) async {
    SecurePreferences().setString(SecurePreferencesKeys.key_idScaleLocalization, taskId);
    idScale = taskId;

    if (_receivePort == null) {
      _receivePort = ReceivePort();
      _isolate = await Isolate.spawn(_isolateEntry, [_receivePort!.sendPort, taskId]);

      _receivePort!.listen((message) {
        if (message is SendPort) {
          message.send(taskId);
        } else if (message is String) {
          _streamController.add(message);
        }
      });
    }
  }

  Future<String> continueSharingLocation(String id) async {
    idScale = await SecurePreferences().getString(SecurePreferencesKeys.key_idScaleLocalization);

    if (idScale != null && idScale != '') {
      startTask(idScale);
      return idScale;
    } else {
      return id;
    }
  }

  // Stop task
  void stopTask() {
    idScale = null;
    _receivePort = null;
    _receivePort?.close();
    _streamController.close();
    _isolate?.kill(priority: Isolate.immediate);
    SecurePreferences().clearData(SecurePreferencesKeys.key_idScaleLocalization);
  }

  Future<Coordinates> getLocation() async {
    requestPermission();
    final position = await geolocatorPosition();
    return Coordinates(lat: position.latitude, lng: position.longitude);
  }
}


I need this BackgroundData class to send updates every 30 seconds and dispose of all functions when necessary.

No.  The stores won't let you.  It'd make their phones look bad because of extremely shortened battery life.

That's sad. Thank you.
